# CRM : Can not set lastusedincampaign field while creating entity

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I am creating a new `contact` record and I need to set `lastusedincampaign` field while creating. But my entity is being created with empty `lastusedincampaign` field.
I only can set it programatically with `Update` method after `Create`.

Where the problem can be?

P.S.: Creating and then updating my entity record is not a good idea, cause I have about 4k entity records to create at once.

**UPDATE 1 (test code):**

```
Entity contact = new Entity("contact");
contact["fullname"] = "New contact";
contact["lastusedincampaign"] = DateTime.UtcNow;
CrmHelper.InitializeCrmService().Create(contact);
```

Comment: Are you using a plugin to set the value? What are you currently doing to set `lastusedincampaign`?

Comment: No, not a plugin. I wrote a custom .net application where I get crm service and then utilize it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like CRM ignores `lastusedincampaign` attribute like it does a few other during create operation. If you do not want to perform create/update operations at the same time, why don't you create a temporary workflow that would run asynchronously and update the field's value? This way async server takes most of the load and the record creations are faster.

Side note 4k records is not an awfully lot of records to perform a create/update simultaneously, I have worked with records in the tens of thousands and CRM never bottle necked on me.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems, it is true. I created a simple code (Update 1) to test exactly this attribute, and as a result, lastusedincampaign field has not been filled.

Workflow and etc is not good for me, cause right after all contacts are created my app is starting to collect statistics.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior you described is expected. If you check the Metadata for the attribute `lastusedincampaign` you will find that the field has `IsValidForCreate` set to `false` and `IsValidForUpdate` set to `true`.

You must update the record after you create it if you want to fill that field.